# Show shift based on when record was completed

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table where we record when an entry was completed.

Using the date entry I would like to determine on what shift this record occurred in.

```
1st shift 6am - 2pm
2nd shift 2pm - 10pm
3rd shift 10pm - 6am
```

Would like to see result as follows.

| order_num | test_iteration | complete_date | shift |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | 12 | 1/23/2023 8:18:36 AM | 1 |

Any ideas or suggestions?

```
select order_num, test_iteration, complete_date
case shift
when ...
```

Am I in the right direction? Not sure what would be the best method to use

Comment: please provide some sample data and desired output

Comment: just add the `shift` column to your order table. Done. The shift will be filled based on time.
What if next year the shift changes to 7-3. Now you query old data and bam - 2nd shift did what last year was first.

Answer (score 3):

Use a `CASE EXPRESSION` as you referenced would be the best approach.

```
create table my_table (
  order_num integer, 
  test_iteration integer, 
  complete_date timestamp
  );
```

```
insert all 
into my_table (order_num, test_iteration, complete_date) values
 (123456, 12, to_date('01/23/2023 12:18:36 AM', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss AM'))
into my_table (order_num, test_iteration, complete_date) values
 (9998, 4, to_date('01/23/2023 8:59:36 AM', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss AM'))  
into my_table (order_num, test_iteration, complete_date) values
 (5446, 2, to_date('01/23/2023 10:00:00 PM', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss AM')) 
into my_table (order_num, test_iteration, complete_date) values
 (654, 3, to_date('01/23/2023 5:00:00 PM', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss AM')) 
select 1 from dual;
```

```
select order_num, test_iteration, complete_date, 
 case
  when extract(hour from complete_date) >= 22  or extract(hour from complete_date) < 6 then 3
  when extract(hour from complete_date) >= 14  and extract(hour from complete_date) < 22 then 2
  else 1
 end shift
from my_table
```

| ORDER_NUM | TEST_ITERATION | COMPLETE_DATE | SHIFT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | 12 | 23-JAN-23 00.18.36.000000 | 3 |
| 9998 | 4 | 23-JAN-23 08.59.36.000000 | 1 |
| 5446 | 2 | 23-JAN-23 22.00.00.000000 | 3 |
| 654 | 3 | 23-JAN-23 17.00.00.000000 | 2 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/C4NieVJQ)

**EDIT**

The expression can be shortened to this, as long as you keep in this order:

```
 case
  when extract(hour from complete_date) >= 22  or extract(hour from complete_date) < 6 then 3
  when extract(hour from complete_date) >= 14  then 2
  else 1
 end shift
```

Answer (score 0):

i will show you example in SQL;

```
declare @dt datetime = '1/23/2023 11:00:00 PM'

select  
    case 
        when cast(@dt as time) between cast('06:00:00 AM' as time) and cast('01:59:59 PM' as time) then 1 
        when cast(@dt as time) between cast('02:00:00 PM' as time) and cast('09:59:59 PM' as time) then 2 
        when cast(@dt as time) between cast('10:00:00 PM' as time) and cast('11:59:59 PM' as time) then 3
        when cast(@dt as time) between cast('00:00:00 AM' as time) and cast('05:59:59 AM' as time) then 3
        else 0 
        end as shift
```

the last 2 rows cover to 12AM and up to morning

Comment: The question is tagged oracle, but this looks like SQL Server syntax.

Comment: @GMB yes, you are correct. but Qracle have different time casting functions. i just gave the approach..

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate it using:

```sql
SELECT order_num,
       test_iteration,
       complete_date,
       FLOOR(EXTRACT(HOUR FROM CAST(complete_date - INTERVAL '6' HOUR AS TIMESTAMP)) / 8) + 1 AS shift
FROM   table_name;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (order_num, test_iteration, complete_date) AS
SELECT 123456, 12, DATE '2023-01-23' + INTERVAL '08:18:36' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT LEVEL, LEVEL, DATE '2023-01-23' + (LEVEL - 1)/24 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 24;
```

Outputs:

| ORDER_NUM | TEST_ITERATION | COMPLETE_DATE | SHIFT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | 12 | 2023-01-23 08:18:36 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 2023-01-23 00:00:00 | 3 |
| 2 | 2 | 2023-01-23 01:00:00 | 3 |
| 3 | 3 | 2023-01-23 02:00:00 | 3 |
| 4 | 4 | 2023-01-23 03:00:00 | 3 |
| 5 | 5 | 2023-01-23 04:00:00 | 3 |
| 6 | 6 | 2023-01-23 05:00:00 | 3 |
| 7 | 7 | 2023-01-23 06:00:00 | 1 |
| 8 | 8 | 2023-01-23 07:00:00 | 1 |
| 9 | 9 | 2023-01-23 08:00:00 | 1 |
| 10 | 10 | 2023-01-23 09:00:00 | 1 |
| 11 | 11 | 2023-01-23 10:00:00 | 1 |
| 12 | 12 | 2023-01-23 11:00:00 | 1 |
| 13 | 13 | 2023-01-23 12:00:00 | 1 |
| 14 | 14 | 2023-01-23 13:00:00 | 1 |
| 15 | 15 | 2023-01-23 14:00:00 | 2 |
| 16 | 16 | 2023-01-23 15:00:00 | 2 |
| 17 | 17 | 2023-01-23 16:00:00 | 2 |
| 18 | 18 | 2023-01-23 17:00:00 | 2 |
| 19 | 19 | 2023-01-23 18:00:00 | 2 |
| 20 | 20 | 2023-01-23 19:00:00 | 2 |
| 21 | 21 | 2023-01-23 20:00:00 | 2 |
| 22 | 22 | 2023-01-23 21:00:00 | 2 |
| 23 | 23 | 2023-01-23 22:00:00 | 3 |
| 24 | 24 | 2023-01-23 23:00:00 | 3 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/QinWpxxB)