# Classify data using dates and hours

Tags: sql, sorting, date, datetime, validation

I'm new to SQL and I'm trying to classify the data I have from some machines to see in which turn each data was generated. I have a table with my original info, I know different schedules that correspond to each shift, and I expect that my final result looks like the 'Expected' table. In this example, the day begins with the schedule of shift 1 (6-14), that is, my day begins at 6 am on the day and ends with shift 3 (22-06), that is, at 6 am the next day, that is why in the example row 3 in the new date field shows the day 02/09/24, because although the transaction originated on the 10th, the time still corresponded to the previous day's time. The date format is DD/MM/YYYY.

Original

| Machine | Value | Original Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 70 | 09/02/2024 13:05 |
| 2 | 50 | 09/02/2024 23:05 |
| 2 | 80 | 10/02/2024 01:01 |

Shifts

| Shift | Hours |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 06:00 - 14:00 |
| 2 | 14:00 - 22:00 |
| 3 | 22:00 - 06:00 |

Expected

| Machine | Value | Original Date | Shift | New Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 70 | 09/02/2024 13:05 | 2 | 09/02/2024 |
| 2 | 50 | 09/02/2024 23:05 | 3 | 09/02/2024 |
| 2 | 80 | 10/02/2024 01:01 | 3 | 09/02/2024 |

Comment: Most people here want sample table data and the expected result as formatted text (not images). Also show us your current query attempt, i.e. provide a complete [mcve].

Comment: And add a tag for the dbms you're using. When it comes to date/time, many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant.

Comment: Why does the 3rd row have an expected new date of 9/2/2024?

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76559547/show-shift-based-on-when-record-was-completed) help with how to determine shift values.

Comment: Your life would be much easier if your shift table had different columns for the start and end times. As a general rule, never put multiple values in the same field